# VS Code Git Extension API

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, api-design, vscode-extensions

Is there somewhere one can obtain more documentation on how to create an extension that uses the Git Extension API?

At https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/git/README.md the only documentation Microsoft provides is this:

## Git integration for Visual Studio Code

**Notice:** This extension is bundled with Visual Studio Code. It can be disabled but not uninstalled.

### Features

See [Git support in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_git-support) to learn about the features of this extension.

### API

The Git extension exposes an API, reachable by any other extension.

1. Copy `src/api/git.d.ts` to your extension's sources;
2. Include `git.d.ts` in your extension's compilation.
3. Get a hold of the API with the following snippet:

   ```
   const gitExtension = vscode.extensions.getExtension<GitExtension>('vscode.git').exports;
   const git = gitExtension.getAPI(1);
   ```

It really doesn't help and when I try to use those 2 lines the extension runs but if I try to check, for example, git.repositories[0] it returns undefined. Idk if I'm doing something wrong? :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a look at [`eamodio/vscode-gitlens`](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens), the main extension based on Git extension.

Its [`src/git/gitService.ts`](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/blob/30e1d290e8f337d56596a030ff097eeabdd98eb7/src/git/gitService.ts#L3042-L3053) does call the GIt extension:

```
static async getBuiltInGitApi(): Promise<BuiltInGitApi | undefined> {
    try {
        const extension = extensions.getExtension('vscode.git') as Extension<GitExtension>;
        if (extension !== undefined) {
            const gitExtension = extension.isActive ? extension.exports : await extension.activate();

            return gitExtension.getAPI(1);
        }
    } catch {}

    return undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To further complement the existing answer, and for those who do not code in TypeScript but raw JavaScript:

A call to `gitExtension.getAPI(1)` will give you an instance of [`API`](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/blob/6cfd9fdedd7c6ec3bfa732af7c418bbbecdfba54/src/%40types/git.d.ts#L179) that is only useful for its `.repositories` member. This member is an array of [`Repository`](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/blob/6cfd9fdedd7c6ec3bfa732af7c418bbbecdfba54/src/%40types/git.d.ts#L122) instances, one for each of your workspace repo. From such instances, you can do all git actions.

However, I must admit that this API is still poorly documented, as most functions accept strings, and it's not always obvious what they should be if you are not familiar with git language. I ended up using `simple-git` node module. It has proper documentation and is faster to achieve the functionality you want without losing too much time here.