# Is there a way to see if a file is source controlled and get its GitHub repo URL?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github, vscode-extensions

Given a path of a file or folder that is in a VS Code workspace, is there an API I can use to determine if it's Git-controlled and look up the associated remote repository URL? This would be for a custom extension.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.  It gets the workspace folder of the file you are interested in.  And then checks if that is one of the git repositories that you have opened - it works for single root or multiroot workspaces where a file may be in a root folder that may or may not be in a git repo.

```js
    const gitExtension = vscode.extensions.getExtension('vscode.git').exports;
    const api = gitExtension.getAPI(1);

    // some file you are interested in, get a uri from it
    // note forward slashes
    const myUri = vscode.Uri.file('C:/Users/Mark/OneDrive/TestMultiRoot/Test.js');

    // note double backslashes also work
    // const myUri = vscode.Uri.file('C:\\Users\\Mark\\OneDrive\\TestMultiRoot\\Test.js');

    // below single backslashes - DO NOT WORK
    // const myUri = vscode.Uri.file('C:\Users\Mark\OneDrive\command-alias\scratchpad.txt');

    const repo = api.repositories.find(repo => {
        // to test current editor, below returns the workspaceFolder
        // const inThisFolder = vscode.workspace.getWorkspaceFolder(vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri);
        
        const inThisFolder = vscode.workspace.getWorkspaceFolder(myUri);
        return inThisFolder?.uri?.fsPath === repo?.rootUri?.fsPath;
    });

    if (!repo) return;  // no git repo for this file
    const repoPath = repo.repository.remotes[0].fetchUrl;
    // repoPath is like "https://github.com/ArturoDent/command-alias.git"

    // note that 'remotes' is an array, it will contain CLONES of the original repository
    // but it appears that remotes[0] is the current working repository you are interested in, check
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/59442538 and [Git integration for Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/git/README.md) especially the part about `extensionDependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answers your question, but if it is something you are working on, there is a hidden git folder in the root folder. ".git" which has a config file with the remote url listed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [the GitHub PR extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github), you should be able to just right click in the gutter (the place between the line numbers and the editor text area) and there will be actions for copying the GitHub path.